# How to wait for a process that has been started on a remote computer using ssh in a script?

Tags: python, ssh, cross-platform, paramiko

I have a script that, in a specific case is required to run a very time-consuming script on a remote computer. I currently do this with:

```
if specific_case:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect('10.0.0.1', username='username', password='password')
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('tmux new-session -d -s session_name \'python /home/username/flamethrower.py'\'')
```

Now - so far so good.. How could I wait for `python /home/username/flamethrower.py` in the script that initially started it and possibly have a minimalistic feedback?

The computer running the script that starts `flamethrower.py` on the remote computer is a windows 8.1, the computer where `flamethrower.py` is run, is a Debian wheezy.

pseudo coded:

```
[...] # as above
while not stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('tmux new-session -d -s session_name \'python /home/username/flamethrower.py'\''):

    #while it's not done, print a dot every minute
    sys.stdout.print('.')
    sys.flush()
    sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your remote script output to some log file, including when finished, then poll the remote connection every so often for the finish output, (and fetch the remaining output).

Comment: That's an idea I had as well, thank you very much for the suggestion!